# How to show that $S_{n+1}>S_n$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Let $S_n = \int_0^{\pi /2}(x\sin{x})^ndx$ for all integer $n\geq1$.

I want to show that $S_{n+1}>S_n$ for all integer $n\geq1$.

Since there is a real $0<a<\frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $a\sin{a}=1$,

we have  $\int_a^{\pi /2}(x\sin{x})^{n+1}dx>\int_a^{\pi /2}(x\sin{x})^{n}dx$

but $\int_0^{a}(x\sin{x})^{n+1}dx<\int_0^{a}(x\sin{x})^{n}dx$.

So we can't conclude it is true.

How to prove that $S_{n+1}>S_n$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $n$ big enough you can use your argument to prove the claim. This is because in the segment $[0,a]$ the integral will be positive but very small, so that increasing $n$ will not decrease the entire integral too much. On the other hand, near $x=\pi/2$ you multiply the function by almost $\pi/2$ which will increase it exponentially in $n$.

Comment: @Chilango For $x$ near $\pi/2$, $x\sin x > 1$, so your claim that $(x\sin x)^{n+1} \le (x\sin x)^n$ is false.

Comment: you are right.  thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a$ be the unique real in $(0,\pi/2)$ such that $a\sin a=1$. Now, for $n\ge 1$ we have
$$\eqalign{S_{n+1}-S_n&=\int_a^{\pi/2}(x\sin x-1)(x\sin x)^ndx -\int_0^a(1-x\sin x)(x\sin x)^ndx\cr
&\ge\int_a^{\pi/2}(x\sin x-1)(x\sin x)dx -\int_0^a(1-x\sin x)(x\sin x)dx\cr
&=S_{2}-S_1=\frac{\pi^3}{48}+\frac{\pi}{8}-1\approx0.038>0.
}$$
And the desired conclusion follows.

**Another approach.** Since
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(x\sin x-1)^2(x\sin x)^ndx>0$$
We conclude that $S_{n+2}-2S_{n+1}+S_{n}>0$, so
$(S_{n+1}-S_{n})_{n\ge1}$ is increasing, and the conclusion follows from $S_{2}-S_1>0$.